# How to implement aws cloudfront in my laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Here is the code already used in my laravel application. This code directly get image url from my s3 storage. But I need to implement cloudfront and generate signed url for to get and download images.

```
foreach($fileInfos['files'] as $file) {
       $dlFileName = $file['name'];
       $fileDLUrls[] = FileIO::getUrl(FILE_ORIGINAL_DIRECTORY . '/'.$file['path'], $effectiveTime, ['ResponseContentType' => 
'application/octet-stream','ResponseContentDisposition' => 
'attachment; filename*=UTF-8\'\''. rawurlencode($dlFileName)]);
}
```

```
    public static function getUrl($fullPathName, $expires = '+1440 minutes', $headers = [])
    {
        if ($fullPathName == '') {
            return null;
        }

        switch (Storage::getDefaultDriver()) {
            case 's3':
                $disk = Storage::disk('s3');
                $headers = array_merge([
                    'Bucket' => env('AWS_S3_BUCKET'),
                    'Key' => $fullPathName
                ], $headers);
                $command = $disk->getDriver()
                    ->getAdapter()
                    ->getClient()
                    ->getCommand('getObject', $headers);
                $request = $disk->getDriver()
                    ->getAdapter()
                    ->getClient()
                    ->createPresignedRequest($command, $expires);
                return (string) $request->getUri();
            case 'local':
                return URL::to('/' . env('AWS_LOCAL_UPLOADDIR')) .
                         '/' . $fullPathName;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

I have changed above code as below,

```
public static function getUrl($fullPathName, $expires = '+1440 minutes')
    {
        if ($fullPathName == '') {
            return null;
        }


        switch (Storage::getDefaultDriver()) {
            case 's3':
                $resourceKey = env('CLOUDFRONT_URL').$fullPathName . '?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DDummy_Title_Card%20%283rd%20copy%29.jpeg';
                $expired = strtotime($expires);
                $privateKey = env('AWS_PRIVATE_KEY');
                $keyPairId = env('AWS_KEY_PAIR_ID');
                
                $cloudFrontClient = new CloudFrontClient([
                    'profile' => 'default',
                    'version' => '2014-11-06',
                    'region' => env('AWS_REGION')
                ]);
                    $result = $cloudFrontClient->getSignedUrl([
                        'url' => $resourceKey,
                        'expires' => $expired,
                        'private_key' => $privateKey,
                        'key_pair_id' => $keyPairId,
                        
                    ]);
                    
                    return $result;
            case 'local':
                return URL::to('/' . env('AWS_LOCAL_UPLOADDIR')) .
                    '/' . $fullPathName;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

But I didn't use the headers in the first code. So that am not able to download the images.
Can anyone help me to know about the reason or any solutions?

Comment: `So that am not able to download the images.` Provide details on the error or unexpected results. Also, what does this mean `But I didn't use the headers in the first code.`? If you mean PHP includes, show what you are using.

Comment: Why have you tagged `laravel-5`? Laravel 5 is ancient.

Comment: Currently, I can get the images through the CloudFront URL, but I cannot download those images even if I append Content-Disposition in url.